# How to scrape data from a specific website

Tags: python, html

I am trying to **scrape** data from a website to make an analysis for practicing. I am having some issues with a specific website. The website is about the police report in the Seattle area. I have read plenty of articles and could not get the answer. The URL is: https://data.seattle.gov/Public-Safety/real-time-911/nvqc-w7eg

I know that I should use beautiful soup and try to find a keyword to do the search afterwards transform the type to text. However, I keep getting None.

```py
import requests

URL = 'https://data.seattle.gov/Public-Safety/real-time-911/nvqc-w7eg'
page = requests.get(URL) 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
```

My goal is to transform the table into a `.csv` file. Could someone help me please?

Comment: If the table is created by JS, this approach won't work

Comment: For JavaScript heavy sites like the one you are interested in you should probably try [Selenium with it's Python API](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead of requests, which does not work well with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating BeautifulSoup object:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
```

or,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
```

or,

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

I think, you should use `lxml` because it has good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the HTML with either `lxml` or `html.parser`. Some have advantages over the other including the fact that `lxml` is very fast.

```
URL = 'https://data.seattle.gov/Public-Safety/real-time-911/nvqc-w7eg'
page = requests.get(URL) 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser") #or lxml, htmlparser is just example
```

Instead of putting it directly inside without the string, put it in with the string so that Python knows that you're dealing with parsers.